# The blue one's car is burning AND The blue ones' car is burning

Tags: possessives

Can we use the possessive "'s" for "one"

> -I am seeing a green guy and a blue one.
>
> -The blue one's car is burning

Is it correct?

The same about pluraul:

> -I am seeing green guys blue ones.
>
> -The blue ones' car is burning

Correct?

Comment: You're exactly right.

Comment: Yes, if multiple blue men have joint ownership of a single car. (Or ownership in the loose sense of all of them being inside it or next to it at the time.)